# Receiving mails in Android app - program always stops immediately on "connect" method

Tags: android

I have a problem with receiving mails in Android app - program always stops immediately on "connect" method:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps"); 
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(host, user, password);
```

No matter it's imap or pop3, gmail or other account, filled properties or not, phone or emulator - it always stops here with no reason. I'm compiling for platform 2.3.3 (API 10). Do you have any ideas what's wrong and what I can do to fix it?

Same situation when I try to get some file using:

```
URL url = new URL(sURL);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpCon.connect();
```

-- it also stops after connect, although this time program stops only in emulator, on the phone it's still running, but never pass "connect"...

Comment: I cant remember myself, but can you set breakpoints to inspect things when sonething goes wrong, and have you?

Comment: yeah, I have used debugger, and after this line it takes to some android classes with no sources, and then program breaks, so it's hard to tell why it happens :(

Comment: So there are no errors anywhere?

Comment: Yes, no specific error. It's in try clausule and doesn't even fall into catch, program just stops after "connect".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I feel ashamed, because I just forgot to add permission "android.permission.INTERNET" in AndroidManifest.xml, and that was the reason why connect doesn't work in my case :)